# Libwebsockets libwebsocket_client_connect function parameters

Tags: libwebsockets

This is the signature of `libwebsocket_client_connect()`

```
struct libwebsocket * libwebsocket_client_connect(
struct libwebsocket_context * context, 
const char * address, int port, int ssl_connection, const char *path, 
const char * host, const char * origin, 
const char * protocol, int ietf_version_or_minus_one)
```

here could anyone explain what does path parameter means?

In doc its written as path - websocket path on server.
But i couldnt its proper meaning.

Answer (score 1):

path refers to the `path` where the websockets endpoint/uri is located on the server.

When you run the sample code for websocket server available online, the server generally runs at `localhost:9000` .Here is there is no path and you can give `"/"` as path in `libwebsocket_client_connect()`.

But in some cases the server may be running at a specified uri on the server like `www.myserver:9000/inside/inside/websockets/endpoint`

In above case the path is `"/inside/inside/websockets/endpoint"`